# What does rr.reshape(rr,(a,b)) TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, numpy, transpose

what does the error rr.reshape(rr,(a,b))
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
I can not understand this my array is one dimensional only but I am unable to perform reshape opertion.

I have seen that my array is one dimensional but I cant perform reshape
operation

```
import numpy
a1=[]
a2=[]
a,b =(raw_input().split())
a=int(a)
b=int(b)
a1=raw_input().split()
a2=raw_input().split()
a1=list(map(int,a1))
a2=list(map(int,a2))
a1.extend(a2)
rr=numpy.array(a1)
print(rr)
rr.reshape(rr,(a,b))"""THe error line"""
print(rr)
```

please help me doing this program

Comment: `rr.reshape` (a.k.a. [`numpy.ndarray.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html?highlight=numpy.ndarray.reshape#numpy.ndarray.reshape)) is not the same as [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `reshape` in `numpy` you can either do

```
arrayname.reshape(shape)
```

or

```
numpy.reshape(arrayname, shape)
```

So use `rr.reshape((a,b))`.

In general, try looking at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape) before posting such questions. Most of your posted code is not relevant to the question. Try to construct a minimal working example.